# Плагин виртуальной клавиатуры (появление клавиатуры при получении фокуса)

Tags: jquery, плагин

Доброго времени суток! Нужен `jQuery` плагин виртуальной клавиатуры, чтобы клавиатура появлялась при получении фокуса полем. Может кто-нибудь подсказать такой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jquery virtual keyboard](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/virtual_keyboard) , например.
Или [такой](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/)

А вообще, напишите свой: 
В цикле создается div:

```
<div id="virtual_keyboard">
<button id="q" type="button">Q</button>
<button id="w" type="button">W</button>
<button id="e" type="button">E</button>
<button id="r" type="button">R</button>
<button id="t" type="button">T</button>
<button id="y" type="button">Y</button>
...
</div>
```

При нажатии на нужное поле

```
$("#my_textfield").click(function(){
//назначается активное поле
$("#virtual_keyboard").data('active-field','my_textfield').show();
});

$('#virtual_keyboard').find('button').click(function(){
  if($(this).data('active-field')!=''){
    active_field = $('#'+$(this).data('active-field'));
    active_field.val(active_field.val()+$(this).text());
  }
});
```

Можно чуток усложнить, чтобы оно ловило где расположен курсор. Но это уже на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: то что вы написали здесь плагином не является, к тому-же это явный набор плохих советов.

Comment: >это явный набор плохих советов

А вы как всегда кратки в своих суждениях.=)
Влом пару строк махнуть что именно? За коментарии не бьют тут... ;)

Comment: ну во первых, раскладку лучше строкой или массивом объявлять, 

во вторых, если говорим плагин, то пишем 

    (function ($) {
            $.fn.pluginName = function () {    
        }
    })(jQuery)

в третьих, привязываем click непосредственно к объекту кнопки (вместо привязки id к каждому элементу), генерируем событие нажатой клавиши в input

в четвертых - используем focusin/focusout вместо click.

Comment: Критика принята. Только по поводу раскладки не понял. Как из строки собрать виджет клавиатуры? Только циклом, разве еще как-то?

Comment: ну например так 

    "`1234567890-=B:qwertyuiop[]:Lasdfghjkl;'\E:Szxcvbnm,./S:CA AC"

: -разделитель, большие буквы - спецклавиши (отдельно описывать) если надо переключение, то массив layout в вашей второй ссылке есть годный формат описания раскладок (там наборы массивов) 

вообще кейбордный плагин не такое уж простое дело :)

Answer (score 2):

[Virtual Keyboard](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/index.html)